# Personalize a rectangle node tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

What I want to do is reproduce this example:
[image]

and my code is the following (a little bit long, sorry):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\tikzset{
noeudA/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=25mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=green!30,
  minimum height = 10mm
  },
noeudB/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=25mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=green!20,
  minimum height = 10mm
  },
noeudC/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=20mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=green!10,
  minimum height = 12mm
  },
noeudD/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=20mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=blue!10,
  minimum height = 10mm
  },
feuille/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=20mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=blue!10,
  minimum height = 10mm
  },
segment/.style={
 very thick
 }
}

\def\DistanceInterFeuilles{1.3}

\def\NiveauA{0}
\def\NiveauB{-2}
\def\NiveauC{-4}
\def\NiveauD{-6}

% Noeuds (MODIFIABLES : Styles et Coefficients d'InterFeuilles)
\node[noeudA] (R) at (0,{\NiveauA}) {SCR};

\node[noeudB] (Ra) at (-4,{\NiveauB}) {Ajustement};
\node[noeudB] (Rb) at (0,{\NiveauB}) {BSCR};
\node[noeudB] (Rc) at (4,{\NiveauB}) {Opérationnel};

\node[noeudC] (Rba) at (-7.5, {\NiveauC}) {Marché};
\node[noeudC] (Rbb) at (-4.5, {\NiveauC}) {Santé};
\node[noeudC] (Rbc) at (-1.5, {\NiveauC}) {Contre-partie};
\node[noeudC] (Rbd) at (1.5, {\NiveauC}) {Vie};
\node[noeudC] (Rbe) at (4.5, {\NiveauC}) {Non-vie};
\node[noeudC] (Rbf) at (7.5, {\NiveauC}) {Actifs incorporels};

% Noeud Marché
\node[noeudD] (Rbaa) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (1)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Taux d'intérêt};
\node[noeudD] (Rbab) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (2)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Action};
\node[noeudD] (Rbac) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (3)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Immobilier};
\node[noeudD] (Rbad) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (4)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Spread};
\node[noeudD] (Rbae) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (5)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Change};
\node[noeudD] (Rbaf) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (6)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Concen\-tration};
\node[noeudD] (Rbag) at (-8,{\NiveauD - (7)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Illiquidité};

% Noeud Santé
\node[noeudD] (Rbba) at (-5.5,{\NiveauD}) {SLT};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbaa) at (-5.5, {\NiveauD - (1)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Mortalité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbab) at (-5.5, {\NiveauD - (2)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Longévité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbac) at (-5.5, {\NiveauD - (3)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbad) at (-5.5, {\NiveauD - (4)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Rachat};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbae) at (-5.5,{\NiveauD - (5)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5} ) {Dépenses };
\node[noeudD] (Rbbaf) at (-5.5, {\NiveauD - (6)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Révision};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbb) at (-3.25,{\NiveauD}) {Catastrophe};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbc) at (-1, {\NiveauD}) {NSLT};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbca) at (-1, {\NiveauD - (1)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Prime et réserve};
\node[noeudD] (Rbbcb) at (-1, {\NiveauD - (2)*\DistanceInterFeuilles -0.5}) {Rachat};

% Noeud Vie
\node[noeudD] (Rbda) at (2,{\NiveauD - (1)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Mortalité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbdb) at (2,{\NiveauD - (2)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Longévité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbdc) at (2,{\NiveauD - (3)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[noeudD] (Rbdd) at (2,{\NiveauD - (4)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Rachat};
\node[noeudD] (Rbde) at (2,{\NiveauD - (5)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Dépenses};
\node[noeudD] (Rbdf) at (2,{\NiveauD - (6)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Révision};
\node[noeudD] (Rbdg) at (2,{\NiveauD - (7)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Catas\-trophe};

% Noeud Non Vie
\node[noeudD] (Rbea) at (4.5,{\NiveauD - (1)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Prime et réserve};
\node[noeudD] (Rbeb) at (4.5,{\NiveauD - (2)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Rachat};
\node[noeudD] (Rbec) at (4.5,{\NiveauD - (3)*\DistanceInterFeuilles}) {Catas\-trophe};

\coordinate (interm1) at (0,-1);
\draw[segment] (R)-- (interm1) -| (Ra);
\draw[segment] (R)--(Rb);
\draw[segment] (R)-- (interm1) -| (Rc);

\coordinate (interm2) at (0,-3);
\draw[segment] (Rb) -- (interm2) -| (Rba);
\draw[segment] (Rb)-- (interm2) -| (Rbb);
\draw[segment] (Rb)-- (interm2) -| (Rbc);
\draw[segment] (Rb)-- (interm2) -| (Rbd);
\draw[segment] (Rb)-- (interm2) -| (Rbe);
\draw[segment] (Rb)-- (interm2) -| (Rbf);

\coordinate (interm3) at (-9.5,-5.5);
\draw[segment] (Rba)|-(interm3);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbaa);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbab);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbac);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbad);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbae);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbaf);
\draw[segment] (interm3)|-(Rbag);

\coordinate (interm4) at (-4.5,-5);
\draw[segment] (Rbb)-- (interm4) -| (Rbba);
\draw[segment] (Rbb)-- (interm4) -| (Rbbb);
\draw[segment] (Rbb)-- (interm4) -| (Rbbc);

\coordinate (interm5) at (-4,-7);
\draw[segment] (Rbba)|-(interm5);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbaa);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbab);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbac);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbad);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbae);
\draw[segment] (interm5)|-(Rbbaf);

\coordinate (interm6) at (-2.4,-7);
\draw[segment] (Rbbc)|-(interm6);
\draw[segment] (interm6)|-(Rbbca);
\draw[segment] (interm6)|-(Rbbcb);

\coordinate (interm7) at (0.5,-5.5);
\draw[segment] (Rbd)|-(interm7);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbda);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbdb);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbdc);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbdd);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbde);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbdf);
\draw[segment] (interm7)|-(Rbdg);

\coordinate (interm8) at (6,-5.5);
\draw[segment] (Rbe)|-(interm8);
\draw[segment] (interm8)|-(Rbea);
\draw[segment] (interm8)|-(Rbeb);
\draw[segment] (interm8)|-(Rbec);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The color are arbitrary, but as you can see on the example, some rectangle have a little triangle in the upper right corner, and I would like to reproduce that. For me, the rectangles appear as node style, but I don't know how to add extras on it.

Comment: Also, if you have advice to shorten the code, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility might be to add a `path picture` to the style, e.g.

```
path picture={
   \fill [green!50!black] ([xshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -| ([yshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
  }
```

So if you have

```
noeudA/.style={
  rectangle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=25mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=green!30,
  minimum height = 10mm,
  path picture={
   \fill [green!50!black] ([xshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -| ([yshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
  }
  }
```

Then the first node of your diagram will look like

[image]

Alternatively you could make a new `upperlefttriangle` style where the color is an argument, i.e.

```
upperlefttriangle/.style={
path picture={
   \fill [#1] ([xshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -| ([yshift=-4mm]path picture bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
  }
}
```

And then use

```
upperlefttriangle={<color>}
```

either in other styles, or in individual nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 10):

[image]

MWE, much more concise as provided MWE (after a some, actually lot of effort :) ) combine `trees` and `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, trees}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 2mm,
    start chain = going below,
base/.style = {rectangle, draw,
               fill=#1,
               inner sep=0mm,
               minimum height = 9mm, text width=25mm, align=center,
               font=\linespread{.9}\selectfont
               },
   T/.style = {path picture={\fill[cyan!75]
                (\ppbb.east) -- (\ppbb.north east) -- ++ (-4.5mm,0) -- cycle;
                             }% end of path picture
               },
boxB/.style = {base=#1, text width=20mm},
% on chain
 box/.style = {boxB=#1, on chain},
% tree's parameters
  level distance = 18mm,
sibling distance = 32mm,
  level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 25mm},
  level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 22mm}
                        ]
% first part of image
% start of tree
\node[base=teal!30] {SCR}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child { node[base=teal!30]      {Ajustement}}
    child { node[base=teal!30,T]    {BSCR}
        child { node[boxB=teal!15,T]    (Rba)   {Marché}}
        child { node[boxB=teal!15,T]    (Rbb)   {Santé}
            child { node[boxB=teal!10,T](Rca)   {SLT}}
            child { node[boxB=teal!10,T](Rcb)   {Catastrophe}}
            child { node[boxB=teal!10]  (Rcc)   {NSLT}}
                }
        child { node[boxB=teal!15,T]    (Rbc)  {Contre-partie}}
        child { node[boxB=teal!15,T]    (Rbd)  {Vie}}
        child { node[boxB=teal!15]      (Rbe)  {Non-vie}}
        child { node[boxB=teal!15]      (Rbf)  {Actifs incorporels}}
            }
    child { node[base=teal!30]  {Opérationnel}};
% Noeud Marché
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rba.west |- Rca.south]   (a);
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbaa) {Taux d'intérêt};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbab) {Action};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbac) {Immobilier};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbad) {Spread};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbae) {Change};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbaf) {Concen\-tration};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbag) {Illiquidité};
}
% Noeud Santé
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rcb.south west]   (b);
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbaa)  {Mortalité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbab)  {Longévité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbac)  {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbad)  {Rachat};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbae)  {Dépenses };
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbbaf)  {Révision};
}
% Noeud NSLT
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rcc.south east -| Rbc.east]   (c);
\node[box=blue!10] (Rbbca)  {Prime et réserve};
\node[box=blue!10] (Rbbcb)  {Rachat};
}
% Noeud Vie
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below left=of Rcc.south -| Rbe.west]    (d);
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbda) {Mortalité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbdb) {Longévité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbdc) {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbdd) {Rachat};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbde) {Dépenses};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbdf) {Révision};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbdg) {Catas\-trophe};
}
% Noeud Non Vie
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below left=of Rcc.south -| Rbf.west]    (e);
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbea)   {Prime et réserve};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbeb)   {Rachat};
\node[box=blue!10,T] (Rbec)   {Catas\-trophe};
}
% lines a
\coordinate[left=of Rbaa.west] (aa);
\draw   (Rba) -- ++ (0,-0.9) -| (aa) -- (Rbaa);
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \ii (initially a)] in {b,c,...,g}
    \draw (aa |- Rba\ii) |- (Rba\i);
% lines b
\draw   (Rca) |- (Rbbaa);
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \ii (initially a)] in {b,c,...,f}
    \draw (Rca |- Rbba\ii) |- (Rbba\i);
% lines d
\draw   (Rcc) |- (Rbbca);
\draw   (Rcc) |- (Rbbcb);
% lines e
\draw   (Rbd) |- (Rbda);
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \ii (initially a)] in {b,c,...,g}
    \draw (Rbd |- Rbd\ii) |- (Rbd\i);
% lines f
\draw   (Rbe) |- (Rbea);
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \ii (initially a)] in {b,c}
    \draw (Rbe |- Rbe\ii) |- (Rbe\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
in the case, when all nodes in second part of block diagram have the same color, than the code of this part can be further reduced:

```
% second part of image
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style = {box=blue!10}] % define common style for all nodes in scope   
% Noeud Marché
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rba.west |- Rca.south]   (a);
\node[T] (Rbaa) {Taux d'intérêt};
\node[T] (Rbab) {Action};
\node[T] (Rbac) {Immobilier};
\node[T] (Rbad) {Spread};
\node[T] (Rbae) {Change};
\node[T] (Rbaf) {Concen\-tration};
\node[T] (Rbag) {Illiquidité};
}
% Noeud Santé
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rcb.south west]   (b);
\node[T] (Rbbaa)  {Mortalité};
\node[T] (Rbbab)  {Longévité};
\node[T] (Rbbac)  {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[T] (Rbbad)  {Rachat};
\node[T] (Rbbae)  {Dépenses };
\node[T] (Rbbaf)  {Révision};
}
% Noeud NSLT
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below=of Rcc.south east -| Rbc.east]   (c);
\node  (Rbbca)  {Prime et réserve};
\node  (Rbbcb)  {Rachat};
}
% Noeud Vie
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below left=of Rcc.south -| Rbe.west]    (d);
\node[T] (Rbda) {Mortalité};
\node[T] (Rbdb) {Longévité};
\node[T] (Rbdc) {Incapacité Invalidité};
\node[T] (Rbdd) {Rachat};
\node[T] (Rbde) {Dépenses};
\node[T] (Rbdf) {Révision};
\node[T] (Rbdg) {Catas\-trophe};
}
% Noeud Non Vie
{[start chain]
\coordinate[on chain,below left=of Rcc.south -| Rbf.west]    (e);
\node[T] (Rbea)   {Prime et réserve};
\node[T] (Rbeb)   {Rachat};
\node[T] (Rbec)   {Catas\-trophe};
}
    \end{scope}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: why lines (joining rectangles) are thin and difference width?

Comment: all lines joining nodes are of the same width. for the width is selected default width (is not explicitly defined). maybe you see differences in their color which are consequence of viewer artifacts. on a paper are all lines the same.